# Tkinter's Widget's built in Virtual Events do not bind

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't seem to get tkinter's built in widget virtual events to work.
It seems that `command =`  works, however I cannot use it because it doesn't return the tkinter event parameters to the callback function.  I need the tkinter event parameter to be returned to the callback so I can get the calling widget's instance.

Am I doing something wrong for `'<<ComboboxSelected>>'`, `'<<Increment>>'`, `'<<Decrement>>'` to do nothing?

I need the callback to be called and the event to be passed so that I can get the widget instance.  I also cannot use lambda (as all of the similar examples suggest) to return the index number as I need to access the widget directly to get its current row number as I intend on deleting rows.  If I use lambda it makes a mess of things as the index is fixed.  So if I click on row 5 and delete row 5, row 6 becomes row 5 and if I want to delete it deletes row 6 instead.

I was also hoping that there was a virtual event for the button to perform the same effect as command.  So if you tab to the button hit spacebar or click on it, but I can't find any such virtual event.  Is there something like this?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

omuVars = []
omuList = ['Bahamas','Canada', 'Cuba','United States']

omu = []
spb = []
cmd = []

def callSelectChanged(event):
    caller = event.widget
    rowNumber = caller.grid_info()['row']
    print(rowNumber)

def callIncrement(event):
    caller = event.widget
    rowNumber = caller.grid_info()['row']
    print(rowNumber)

def callDecrement(event):
    caller = event.widget
    rowNumber = caller.grid_info()['row']
    print(rowNumber)

def callButton(event):
    caller = event.widget
    rowNumber = caller.grid_info()['row']
    print(rowNumber)

for i in range(0,10):
    omuVars.append(StringVar())
    omu.append(OptionMenu(root,
                          omuVars[i],
                          *omuList))
    omu[i].bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', callSelectChanged)
    omu[i].config(font='Terminal 18 bold', anchor=W, fg='blue', relief=FLAT, bg='SystemWindow', borderwidth=0, width=15)
    omu[i].grid(row=i, column=0)

    spb.append(Spinbox(root,
                       from_=00,
                       to=23,
                       wrap=True,
                       width=2,
                       font='Terminal 18 bold',
                       fg='blue',
                       format="%02.0f",
                       relief=FLAT))
    spb[i].bind('<<Increment>>', callIncrement)
    spb[i].bind('<<Decrement>>', callDecrement)
    spb[i].grid(row=i, column=1)

    cmd.append(Button(root,
                      text='\u2718',
                      font='Terminal 16 bold',
                      fg='blue',
                      width=2))
    cmd[i].bind('<Button-1>',callButton)
    cmd[i].bind('<space>', callButton)
    cmd[i].grid(row=i, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tkinter `OptionMenu` widget does not generate a `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event, and the tkinter `Spinbox` widget does not generate an `<<Increment>>` or `<<Decrement>>` event. Binding those events on those widgets will have no effect.

For those events and bindings to work, you need to use the `Combobox` and `Spinbox` widgets from ttk.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that `<<ComboboxSelected>>` is indeed from another control.  
Right, I see now about the ttk also.  Let me look into that, I don't know how much work it would be to move everything from tkinter to ttk.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for event](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/event.htm), `<<Increment>>` and `<<Decrement>>` are not predefined virtual events.

Also, `OptionMenu` does not support `<<ComboboxSelected>>`.
That requires the `ttk.Combobox` widget.

W.r.t. the spinbox, `tkinter` merely invokes `command` when it has changed. This call does not contain an `event`, though.
My workaround to submit different parameters to the same callback this is `functools.partial`.

The `command` callback for `OptionMenu` does not receive an event, but the selected string. See modified code below.

Modified code. I've also used the tk namespace instead of `import *`.

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

omuVars = []
omuList = ["Bahamas", "Canada", "Cuba", "United States"]

omu = []
spb = []
cmd = []


def callSelectChanged(selection):
    print(f"callSelectChanged: {selection}")


def callSpinChanged(index):
    print(f"callSpinChanged: {index}")


def callButton(event):
    caller = event.widget
    rowNumber = caller.grid_info()["row"]
    print(f"callButton: {rowNumber}")


for i in range(0, 10):
    omuVars.append(tk.StringVar())
    omu.append(tk.OptionMenu(root, omuVars[i], *omuList, command=callSelectChanged))
    omu[i].config(
        fg="blue",
        font="Terminal 18 bold",
        relief="flat",
        borderwidth=0,
        width=15,
    )
    omu[i].grid(row=i, column=0)

    spb.append(
        tk.Spinbox(
            root,
            from_=0,
            to=23,
            wrap=True,
            width=2,
            font="Terminal 18 bold",
            fg="blue",
            format="%02.0f",
            relief=tk.FLAT,
            command=partial(callSpinChanged, index=i),
        )
    )
    spb[i].grid(row=i, column=1)

    cmd.append(
        tk.Button(root, text="\u2718", font="Terminal 16 bold", fg="blue", width=2)
    )
    cmd[i].bind("<Button-1>", callButton)
    cmd[i].bind("<space>", callButton)
    cmd[i].grid(row=i, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem.  I cannot use lambda or partial as i remains fixed.  If I delete the row, which is my plan, the i's cannot be used as row numbers as they become non sequencal.  i.e. if I delete row 4, the i in row 4 becomes 5 etc.

Comment: You could use `partial` to supply a reference to the widget as well.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting idea.  Do you have an example of how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Switching from tkinter to ttk solved the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

cmbVars = []
cmbList = ['Bahamas','Canada', 'Cuba','United States']

cmb = []
spb = []
cmd = []

# Define the style for combobox widget
style= ttk.Style(root)
#print(style.theme_names()) #('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
style.theme_use('default')

style.configure("TCombobox", font='Terminal 18 bold' , anchor=tk.W, foreground='blue', relief='flat', background='SystemWindow', borderwidth=0, width=15, arrowcolor='blue', arrowsize=18)
# I don't understand why ttk ignores the following style settings unless I specify it here and in this order.
style.map('TCombobox', fieldbackground=[('readonly','SystemWindow')])  
style.map('TCombobox', selectbackground=[('readonly', 'SystemWindow')])
style.map('TCombobox', selectforeground=[('readonly', 'blue')])

style.configure("TButton", font='Terminal 16 bold', anchor=tk.W, foreground='blue', relief='flat', background='SystemWindow', borderwidth=0, width=2)
style.configure("TSpinbox", font='Terminal 18 bold', anchor=tk.W, foreground='blue', relief='flat', background='SystemWindow', borderwidth=0, width=2, arrowcolor='blue', arrowsize=18)

print()

def callSelectChanged(event):
    caller = event.widget
    rowNumber = caller.grid_info()['row']
    print(rowNumber)

def callIncrement(event):
    caller = event.widget
    rowNumber = caller.grid_info()['row']
    print(rowNumber)

def callDecrement(event):
    caller = event.widget
    rowNumber = caller.grid_info()['row']
    print(rowNumber)

def callButton(event):
    caller = event.widget
    rowNumber = caller.grid_info()['row']
    print(rowNumber)

for i in range(0,10):
    cmbVars.append(tk.StringVar())
    cmb.append(ttk.Combobox(root,
                            textvariable=cmbVars[i],
                            state="readonly",
                            style="TCombobox",
                            font=style.lookup('TCombobox', 'font')))
    cmb[i]['values'] = cmbList
    cmb[i].bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', callSelectChanged)
    cmb[i].grid(row=i, column=0)

    spb.append(ttk.Spinbox(root,
                           from_=00,
                           to=23,
                           wrap=True,
                           format="%02.0f",
                           style="TSpinbox",
                           font=style.lookup('TSpinbox', 'font'),
                           foreground=style.lookup('TSpinbox', 'foreground'),
                           background=style.lookup('TSpinbox', 'background'),
                           width=style.lookup('TSpinbox', 'width')))
    spb[i].bind('<<Increment>>', callIncrement)
    spb[i].bind('<<Decrement>>', callDecrement)
    spb[i].grid(row=i, column=1)

    cmd.append(ttk.Button(root,
                      text='\u2718',
                      style="TButton"))
    cmd[i].bind('<Button-1>',callButton)
    cmd[i].bind('<space>', callButton)
    cmd[i].grid(row=i, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```